# How to use update_elements with rails3-jquery-autocomplete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using rails3-jquery-autocomplete (Rails 3.2.10), and I think I may have two issues which may or may not be interacting.

I have a "name" field (containing a given name) in a table 'pi'.  I want this field to be autocomplete-able, and I want selection of a name in the first field to fill a second, surname field from the same table.

This works for me with 0.6.0 of the gem, but not with 1.0.11.  I can go back and forth between versions, just changing the bundled gem, and have it work or not work.

I gave up on trying to get 1.0.11 to work, happy until I needed to implement filling of the other surname field at the same time.  This I cannot get working in 0.6.0 OR 1.0.11.  I also tried 1.0.10 to no avail.

I'd be happy if I get autocomplete of other fields working with 0.6.0, but I expect that it makes sense for me to figure this out with something current. I'd be grateful if someone could help me get going either way.

My form looks like this:

```
    <%= form_tag do %>
      Given name:  <%= text_field_tag 'name', '', :autocomplete => welcome_autocomplete_pi_name_path, :update_elements => {:surname => '#surname'} %>

      Surname: <%= text_field_tag 'surname', '' %>

    <% end %>
```

The first field id the one that autocompletes with the given name; the surname is not being populated at all.

Controller:

```
    class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
      autocomplete :pi, :name, :extra_data => [:surname]
    end
```

rake routes gives:

```
    $ rake routes
    welcome_show GET /welcome/show(.:format)                 welcome#show
    root     /                                       welcome#show
    welcome_autocomplete_pi_name GET /welcome/autocomplete_pi_name(.:format) welcome#autocomplete_pi_name
```

I did a search but couldn't find anything showing how this works.  The docs seem to suggest that this was straightforward, so I have to assume I am missing something.

thanks for reading !